# Postgres Query to Combine multiple Rows into one based on Status Condition

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a example of below data

```
Col1 Col2 Status
a    ab   Failed
a    bc   Running
a    cd   Completed
```

The output i'm expecting is

```
Col1 Status
a    Failed
```

i.e any one Subjob(Col2) is failed then the Main job should be displayed as Failed

Comment: What do you want to see if there is no failed job at all? e.g. if there was another  row with `b ab Completed`?

Comment: Doesn't `select col1, status from the_table where status = 'Failed'` do what you want?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, 'a' is a main job and the data in 'Col2' are sub jobs of 'a'. So the status in the table is for Sub jobs. Which means if any Sub job failed then the Main Job(Col1) should be set as 'Failed'
If you have another Row b ab then 'b' becomes another main job

Comment: Again: the result you want will be returned by `select col1, status from the_table where status = 'Failed'` and you haven't answered the question what result you want if you have a main job that has no failed sub-jobs

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name if all the Sub jobs are Completed Successfully then the Main Job should be Displayed as 'Succeeded' if not 'NotCompleted'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses `distinct on` and a conditional sort:

```
select distinct on (col1) col1, status
from mytable
order by 
    col1,
    case status
       when 'Failed'    then 0
       when 'Running'   then 1
       when 'Completed' then 2
    end
```

This gives priority to the "Failed" status, followed by "Running", then "Completed".

You could also use booleans for ordering, like:

```
order by 
    col1,
    (status = 'Failed')    desc,
    (status = 'Running')   desc,
    (status = 'Completed') desc
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. it worked but not completely. as it Order by the Status and displays them according to the priority that is set.
But i would like to set the status of Main Job (Col1) as 'NotCompleted' If any of the sub jobs(Col2) is in 'Running' or 'Failed'.
Eg: If  a Sub job has only 'Running' Status then The Final Status Returned will be set to 'Running' and not as 'NotCompleted'

Comment: @ADT All of the information in your comment should have been included in your original question.  This solution addresses what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest answer to the question that you have asked is:

```
select distinct col1, status
from t
where status = 'Failed';
```

This will return all `col1`s that are failed.

If you have a different question, then you should ask it as a *new* question.  Explain your logic clearly, and provide sample data and desired results that covers the main scenarios you need to communicate.